# Remove RTP Header Extensions from RTSP stream in Gstreamer 1.20

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, rtp

I have an RTSP stream with custom metadata RTP Header Extensions and want to remove these from the stream robustly. It looks like Gstreamer 1.20 has a remove header extensions method. How can I use this in a pipeline? Is it correct to use an appsrc/appsink? I'd like to use the method as simply as possible.

Thanks in advance